# how do I implement a single-word auto complete using Elasticsearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I would like to implement an single word autocomplete using elasticsearch 6. I have seen a fair amount of posts on how to do this using lesser versions however, it seems that autocomplete has changed significantly in the last version.

I am using the standard mapping for autocomplete:

```
PUT advertising_tins
{
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "completion_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "completion_filter"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "keyword"
      }
    },
  "filter": {
    "completion_filter": {
      "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": 1,
      "max_gram": 24
    }
  }
}
  },
  "mappings": {
"item": {
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "text"
    },

    "title": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "suggest": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "completion": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "completion_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

I am indexing like this:

```
POST advertising_tins/item/_bulk 
{"index":{}}
{"date": 20180217, "title": "Vintage Spice Cardboard Tin of Mace  Dainty Brand St. Paul, MN  1 oz.","id": "305232814","suggest": [ "spice","cardboard","tin","mace","dainty","brand","st","paul","mn","oz"]}
```

And querying like this:

```
POST advertising_tins/_search?pretty
 {
  "size": 0,
   "query": {
     "term": {
       "suggest.completion": "car"
     }
   },
   "aggs": {
     "suggestions": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "suggest.raw"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

However my results return all terms in the suggest field instead of just single term "cardboard".

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "suggestions": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "brand",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "cardboard",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "dainty",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "mace",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "mn",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "oz",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "paul",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "spice",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "st",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "tin",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
}
 }
}
```

And idea how I fix this and get just a single term match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. It can be achieved with the default [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-suggesters-completion.html), you only need to change the type of your completion field to `"completion"`:

```
"mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "suggest": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "completion": {
              "type" : "completion", <--- here
              "analyzer": "completion_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And add a `"suggest"` part into your query:

```
POST advertising_tins/_search
 {
  "size": 0,
   "query": {
     "term": {
       "suggest.completion": "car"
     }
   },
   "suggest" : {   <--- Here goes he suggest query
    "my-suggestion" : {
      "text" : "car",
      "completion" : {
        "field" : "suggest.completion"
      }
    }
  },
   "aggs": {
     "suggestions": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "suggest.raw"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

The response will look like this:

```
{
  // ...
  "hits": //... ,
  "aggregations": // ...,
  "suggest": {
    "my-suggestion": [
      {
        "text": "car",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 3,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "cardboard",   <--- here is the suggestion
            "_index": "advertising_tins",
            "_type": "item",
            "_id": "GLeUqGEBVrFe7u7pR5uA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "date": 20180217,
              "title": "Vintage Spice Cardboard Tin of Mace  Dainty Brand St. Paul, MN  1 oz.",
              "id": "305232814",
              "suggest": [
                "spice",
                "cardboard",
                "tin",
                "mace",
                "dainty",
                "brand",
                "st",
                "paul",
                "mn",
                "oz"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The response also includes the `_source` of the suggested document, so you might not even need to use `"query"` and `"aggs"` parts.

Hope that helps!